# Why cdn.ckeditor link returned 503 error?

Tags: ckeditor

I added ckeditor on my laravel 8 site with line

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/38.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

abd used it for some time, but just I got error :

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 936549611

Varnish cache server
```

Why this error and how it can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!